# Word Mail Merge with Excel - Can't open both at the same time

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I have a word mail merge for letters using an excel file as the data source. My problem is that I am not able to have both files open at the same time for editing (i.e. the excel source data and the word mail merge file)

When I open excel first, then try to open word, i get an error message that the file is already open in another application and word can't use it!
When I open word first and then try to open it in excel, excel opens it in read-only mode

I would think this is normal, but I've seen many video tutorials on mail merge and it shows both apps

Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

**EDIT:**
I am running Office 2016 on Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Can you post a URL to a sample video that shows what you're trying to do that works for them?

Comment: I don't remember now where I saw them, although I think one was on Lynda.com - However, are you hinting that it is not possible? In short, all I want is to be able open simultaneously 2 documents: 1. my excel file in excel (for editing) 2. Word mail merge document which is using that excel file as it's data source.

Comment: No, not at all :) What I'm thinking is that Word may need to lock the Excel file because it counts the rows/caches some of the data (?) it's being asked to process and if you edit the file then it's got nothing to compare data to in the event it needs to verify the cached data?

Comment: Normally it is OK to open the Excel file first, then open the Word file that connects to it. If you are actually editing the Excel document (e.g. you have modified a cell value and have not moved the insertion point out of the cell,) then Word may not connect and may time out. Opening the Word file first usually does cause problems. *But*, which version of Office, are you using a .xlsx or what? and have you connected in the usual way (OLE DB, though you may not know it)?

Comment: @BigChris That is what it seems like - I just thought I would be able to edit the excel doc during the mail merge, but it seems like not.

Comment: @bibadia, thanks for the comment. However, I've tried opening excel first, but then word won't even load the file since it is in use by a different app.  Regarding the Office/Windows versions - good point, I added that to my original post now. Regarding the connection, I didn't make any special connection - simply chose a data source.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is good news or bad news, or any news... but I found this [thread on microsoft forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e15c7e77-c910-4bf4-9d54-046880328b29/mail-merge-from-word-to-excel-locks-the-excel-document?forum=word) which seems to say that this collaboration is no longer supported. Someone gave a solution of exporting it to HTML and using that as the source data....

Comment: Where are your files located? Using the same Win/Office combination, I can still open an Excel data source in Excel, then open a Word Mail merge document linked to it. I can still modify the data. Some data changes appear when you reselect the modified record in Word. Others (e.g. adding a record) only appear in Word if you go into the Edit Recipient List option and refresh the data source. But if the Excel file is on OneDrive (for example), saving it does result in a locking problem, presumably because another process is involved. Not sure about local Excel files yet.

Comment: @bibadia, My word document is a template which is saved somewhere in %appdata%. As for my excel file, originally it was on Dropbox, but after reading some threads that suggested putting it on a local drive, I did so, but the problem persisted. Please update me on anything else.

Comment: Are you using the template in the traditional way, i.e. to create a new document? A long time ago there was a problem where Word attaches the data source tothe template,then attaches it to the document,"forgetting" that it already has the file/connection open. I thought that had been fixed,but perhaps it still occurs. I used to suggest that the user removed the connection from the template and used a VBA AutoNew or Document_New Sub to make the connection instead.

Comment: @bibadia Thanks a lot for your persistence! Good news and bad news: The good news is that I woke up this morning and everything is working perfectly! I did nothing different, it is just working as expected!!!  The bad news is that we can't figure out the problem.... this thread almost goes to waste - only almost because there some nice points that you mentioned. By the way, I am using the template in the traditional way with a data source.

Comment: @DaveyD: It happens...!